# Independence of $V+W$ and $\frac{V}{V+W}$ when V is Chi square of degree 1 and W is of degree 2

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, chi-squared

I am trying to understand why $V+W$ is independent from $\frac{V}{V+W}$. With $V \sim \chi^2_{(1)}$ and $W \sim \chi^2_{(2)}$. I do not see how this comes about. Note: $V$ and $W$ are independent

I tried deriving the density of $\frac{V}{V+W}$, which to me seems to be some form of Beta, given that cannot be more than $1$ or less than $0$.

$$F_{\frac{V}{V+W}}(\xi)=\int_0^\infty \int_0^{\frac{v-\xi}{1-\xi}}\frac{v^{-1/2}}{2^{1/2}\Gamma(1/2)} \frac{e^{-w^2 /2}}{2} dv dw $$
$$=\frac{1}{2^{1/2}\Gamma(1/2)}[\int_0^\infty v^{-1/2} e^{-1/2}] - \int_0^\infty v^{-1/2}e^{\frac{-v}{2(1-\xi)}}dv$$
$$= 1- \frac{1}{2^{1/2}\Gamma(1/2)}\int_0^\infty v^{-1/2}e^{\frac{-v}{2(1-\xi)}}dv$$
Which now I do not think it is right. I mainly want to be able to understand why $V+W$ is independent of $\frac{V}{V+W}$

Comment: Surely $V$ and $W$ are independent, which you don't mention.

Comment: Indeed! Forgot to add that in, will edit now

Comment: Change variables $(V,W)\to (X,Y)$ such that $X=V+W$ and $Y=V/(V+W)$. Conclude independence of $X$ and $Y$ from the joint density of $(X,Y)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am confused how we would start this. Could you give me some more detail, please?

Comment: Do you know the change of variables/transformation method involving jacobians?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Not too sure... How do we set up the problem? I am having a hard time seeing this. In the above, I tried computing the density for $\frac{V}{V+W}$

Comment: Okay, what do you have to do to show the independence? Is deriving one marginal density sufficient?

Comment: from what I understand, $f_{V,W}(v,w) = f_V(x)f_W(w)$. But from here I do not see how we change variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to independence of $V$ and $W$, joint density of $(V,W)$ is

\begin{align}
f_{V,W}(v,w)&=f_V(v)f_W(w)
\\\\&=\frac{e^{-v/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi v}}\mathbf1_{v>0}\frac{e^{-w/2}}{2}\mathbf1_{w>0}
\\\\&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^{-(v+w)/2}}{\sqrt{v}}\mathbf1_{v>0,w>0}
\end{align}

Transform $(V,W)\to(X,Y)$ such that $$X=\frac{V}{V+W}\quad,\quad Y=V+W$$

Then, $$v=xy\quad,\quad w=y(1-x)$$

Clearly, $$v>0\,,\,w>0\implies 0<x<1\,,\,y>0$$

The Jacobian determinant is $$J=\det\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}&\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}&\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}=\cdots$$

So the joint density of $(X,Y)$ is of the form

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{V,W}(xy,y(1-x))|J|=\cdots$$

Just from the above expression, establish that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ can be factored as the product of two densities. Those are the marginal densities of $X$ and $Y$. Hence the independence of $X$ and $Y$ would be proved.

Comment: I was computing the jacobian when you posted this. Thank you!